# How to access the member and variable of superclass from the subclass in python?

Tags: python

I have a code

```
class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self,story):
        Trigger.stroy=story
        WordTrigger.isWordin(story)
        raise NotImplementedError

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word=word

    def isWordin(self, text):
        rep = text.replace(string.punctuation, '')
        toLower = rep.lower()
        text = toLower.split(' ')
        if(text in self.word):
            return True
        else:
            return False

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
     ...
```

the variable `story` is a class

`class NewsStory:
    def __init__(self,guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        self.guid=guid
        self.title=title
        self.subject=subject
        self.summary=summary
        self.link=link
    def getGuid(self):
        return self.guid
    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title
    def getSubject(self):
        return self.subject
    def getSummary(self):
        return self.summary
    def getLink(self):
        return self.link`

`story=NewsStory(...)` 
How to access the variable `story` and its built in def function in the subclass class `TitleTrigger` ?

Comment: The simplest way is with `Trigger.story`.  `self.story` will also work if you're only reading it (not assigning a new value).  If there's a reason you can't use those, please explain further.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of. One is using class variable and the other an initialized variable. Here's an example that does both:

```
class NewsStory: 
    def __init__(self,guid, title, subject, summary, link): 
        self.guid=guid 
        self.title=title 
        self.subject=subject 
        self.summary=summary 
        self.link=link 

    def getGuid(self): 
        return self.guid 

    def getTitle(self): 
        return self.title 

    def getSubject(self): 
        return self.subject 

    def getSummary(self): 
        return self.summary 

    def getLink(self): 
        return self.link

class Trigger(object):
    story = NewsStory("Guide","title", "subject", "summary","link")

    def __init__(self):
        self.mystory = NewsStory("Guide","title", "subject", "summary","link")

    def evaluate(self,story):
        Trigger.story=story
        WordTrigger.isWordin(story)
        raise NotImplementedError

class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self,word):
        super(WordTrigger, self).__init__()
        self.word=word

    def isWordin(self, text):
        rep = text.replace(string.punctuation, '')
        toLower = rep.lower()
        text = toLower.split(' ')
        if(text in self.word):
            return True
        else:
            return False

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    story = WordTrigger.story

    def __init__(self, word):
        super(TitleTrigger, self).__init__(word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(TitleTrigger.story)

    tt = TitleTrigger("hello")
    print(tt.mystory)
```

The story variable is a class variable, and the mystory variable is an instance variable that's accessed because you can initialize the superclass using something like `super(WordTrigger, self).__init__()`, and then the superclasses variables are available. I hope that helped

Edit:
To access and change title from NewsStory, you can do:

```
print(tt.mystory.title)
tt.mystory.title = "New title"
print(tt.mystory.title)
```

Comment: `story` is not a string variable instead its a class of type `NewsStory`

Comment: My solutions works for any type. I've updated it with your class

Comment: Thank you and how to access the `getTitle` and assign its value to another string variable from function  `TitleTrigger`

Comment: One more doubt how to access the function `evaluate` from TitleTrigger with arguments to `evaluate function as `story.title`

Comment: That's simple, just do: ``tt.evaluate(tt.mystory.title)``

Comment: but TitleTrigger Doesnt have the function evaluate its defined only in the superclass Trigger

Comment: Because you instantiated the superclass, you can still access the ``evaluate`` method by using ``tt.evaluate``. Your declaration ``isWordIn`` method is not a static method, so you can't access it without creating an instance of ``WordTrigger``. You can either make it a static method using the ``@staticmethod`` decorator (put right before the ``def`` and remove the ``self`` parameter), but you would lose all ability to access instance variables (ones prefixed with ``self``. My refactoring your code is beyond what you should want, but this info enough should give you an idea of how to go forward

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50842/discussion-between-hash-and-gyeh)